# Why does merge sort work for any $n$, but the basic FFT algorithm only for powers of $2$?

Tags: divide-and-conquer, mergesort, fast-fourier-transform

Merge sort and FFT are both divide and conquer algorithms that split the input in two repeatedly. While merge sort can be applied to any $n$, the FFT algorithm given in CLRS (section 30.2, third edition) only applies when $n$ is a power of $2$. How come we can forge ahead with any $n$ for merge sort, but not quite for FFT?

Comment: I think the recursive step works fine, but the problem is the halving lemma (lemma 30.5)

Comment: Hi @Rohit, I think you're right, at least for $n$ odd.   The first edition even says about the Halving lemma, "if $n>0$ is even,...".  Again, for $n$ odd, when you take powers greater than $n/2$, you run into problems, since $\left( \omega_{n/2} \right)^{n/2 +1}$ presents problems if you consider the Cancellation lemma.  You would be essentially trying to get an odd power from an even power, or vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

A merge works with individual elements. Any numbers can be handled. In particular, *natural* mergesort does merge sequences of arbitrary lengths.

The FFT works on pairs of elements, with no leftovers. So there must be an even number of them, and by recurrence, a power of $2$.

---

Variants of the FFT can be based on other primes, and can be combined to work for composite $n$, but they don't reach the efficiency of binary FFT.

Comment: What is the significant of "no leftovers"?

Comment: @RohitPandey: the significant ?

Comment: Sorry, meant significance. Wanted to see if you can elaborate on it and why its important.

Comment: @RohitPandey: er, the significance is that it imposes the parity.

Comment: So in merge sort, there are leftovers?